# Automation of test case independent of ui changes

Tags: automation

We are automating test cases for hardware devices like tv, raspberrypi etc which require to perform certain number of steps and check expected result at the end of each step. To automate these test cases we are using dom element attributes such as id, class,data-component-id etc to fetch the objects and perform actions.
The problem with this way of automation is every time UI changes we need to change the dom elements id, class etc and hence it is rework of the scripts.
I want to know if there is automation framework or any other way using which we can automate test cases independent of ui changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the exact path, try to identify the element in a more generic way. Using "contains" will help you to identify the elements with the text attributes with out going into the way it is defined. So even the DOM structure changes but with the text being same, your tests will not fail.

Contains

It is very handy XPath Selenium locator and sometimes it saves the life of a test automation engineer. When an attribute of an element is dynamic, then you can use contains() for the constant part of the web element but also you can use contains() in any condition when you need.

Syntax: //tag[contains(@attribute, ‘value‘)]

Example: //input[contains(@id, ‘er-messa’)]

Examples:

Java
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
//*[contains(@name,'btnClk')]
--> It searches "btnClk" for all name attributes in the DOM.

//*[contains(text(),'here')]
--> It searches the text "here" in the DOM.

//*[contains(@href,'swtestacademy.com')]
--> It searches "swtestacademy.com" link in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you should use `id` selectors if possible. They are supposed to be unique and hence immune to UI changes. The `name` selector should work the same way.

If you are using Selenium, use the following list of object locators in (loosely) this order of preference:

- id
- name
- tag name
- class
- CSS or Xpath
- linktext or partial linktext

And if you really want the elements to be consistently identifiable, you might talk to the developers and ask them nicely to add the ids.